# changing text of <a> tag with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

consider the following html code

```
<a id="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="41" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a id="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="42" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a id="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="43" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a id="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="44" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
```

when user click on cancel, i want to change that corresponding text to be "cancelled",
for this i ve tried the following

```
$(document).on("click", "#retailsale_bill_cancel", function(){
    var bill_no = $(this).attr('bill_no');
    var id_to_delete = $(this).attr('id_to_cancel');

    var request = $.ajax({
                            url: "./php/retailsale_bill_cancel/cancel.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { bill_no: bill_no, id_to_delete: id_to_delete },
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                 //what can i do here to change that <a tags text to "cancelling...."
                            }
                        });

        //WHEN SUCCESS
        request.success(function( data ) {
            //what can i do here to change that <a tags text
        });
        request.done(function(data){

        });
});
```

when googling i came to know about $(this) can solve problem, but i cant get any neat tutorial or examples, 
any help would be helpful,
thanks

Comment: FYI, `id` must be unique.

Comment: You are using `id="retailsale_bill_cancel"` multiple times. IDs must be unique. What do you mean by __id is unique only__?

Comment: my mistake sry, id_to_cancel is unique, can't i use this to change text????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDs must be unique in HTML** and I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attributes. Also I would suggest you to use a common class as selector

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#retailsale_bill_cancel", function(){

    var self= $(this); //Store the refence in another variable like

    var request = ...

        //WHEN SUCCESS
        request.success(function( data ) {
            //what can i do here to change that <a tags text
           self.html('New text');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML can be:

```
<div id="commonAtagsAncestor">
    <a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" data-idCancel="41" data-id="10">cancel</a>
    <a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" data-idCancel="42" data-id="10">cancel</a>
    <a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" data-idCancel="43" data-id="10">cancel</a>
    <a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" data-idCancel="44" data-id="10">cancel</a>
</div>
```

the js attached ...

```
$('#commonAtagsAncestor').click(function(e){
    var $t = $(e.target);

    if($t.is('a.retailsale_bill_cancel')){
        var idcancel = $t.data('idCancel'),
            id =  $t.data('id'),
            request = $.ajax({
              url: "./php/retailsale_bill_cancel/cancel.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                     bill_no: id,
                     id_to_delete: idcancel
              },beforeSend: function(){
                $t.text('cancelling ...'); // Text changed
              }
           });
            e.preventDefault();
        //WHEN SUCCESS
        request.success(function( data ) {
            $t.text('cancelled !');   // Text changed
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: i would like to learn (data-xxx) and (e.target) later but accepted answer is simple to understand for a newbie like me... thanks for ur time...

Answer (score 0):

First, ID must be unique.
Then, use the *[.html](https://api.jquery.com/html/)* method to change the content between the tags.

Exemple:

```
$("#retailsale_bill_cancel_42").html("New text");
```

Comment: if it is the case how can i go with this, on click handler, $(document).on("click", "#retailsale_bill_cancel", function(){

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in which I have shown what you want on a button click

```
var request = $.ajax({
                            url: "./php/retailsale_bill_cancel/cancel.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { bill_no: bill_no, id_to_delete: id_to_delete },
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                 $(this).html("cancelling");

                            }
                        });

        //WHEN SUCCESS
        request.success(function( data ) {
            $(this).html("cancelled");
        });
        request.done(function(data){

        });
```

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/wf8yJ/12/

Answer (score 0):

Please note id of the elements should be unique.
So rather than keeping  the id same for all the elements keep the common attribute as class.
below modification  should work for you.

```
<a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="41" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="42" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="43" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
<a class="retailsale_bill_cancel" id_to_cancel="44" bill_no="10">cancel</a>
```

You can get the clicked element by this

```
var id_to_delete;
$(".retailsale_bill_cancel").click(function(){
      $(this).text("cancelled");
      id_to_delete = $(this).attr('id_to_cancel');
});
```

Now you have proper value in the id_to_delete so now its your logic to do some thing with it.